# how to see stack trace for a particular thread within a hanged process in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, stack-trace, callstack, pstack

I have a multi-threaded process that got stuck while running under Linux. But I don't have multi-threaded version to `pstack` (made alias with `gstack`). As such, `gstack <pid>` does not provide me anything. How can I (a) attach `gdb` to an already running process (b) get stack trace of individual threads (c) know threadids of a running process (d) from threadid (if known) how can I see the stack trace / call stack for a running thread under stuck process?

Comment: For (a) at least, have you read the basic manpage for gdb? For the rest of them, have you read the GDB help pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, compile it with options `-O0 -ggdb` for best debugging.

If you can run in under gdb, just run

```
   # gdb ./yourbinary
```

And just wait problem. When process get stuck, just press `^C` and you in.

If you can't run under gdb, just:

```
   # gdb --pid=<YOUR PID>
```

At both cases, type `info threads` and you will see all your threads. Then select one and you can see `bt` or anything else.